# Understanding chi squared minimization

Tags: statistics, optimization, chi-squared

I have a basic Chi squared:

$$X^2=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{(X_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}$$

I ask myself for which $\sigma$ and $\mu$ my function $X^2$ is minimal, so I suppose this is when the derivate of $X^2$ versus $\sigma$ and $\mu$  equals $0$.

$\frac{\partial(X^2)}{\partial \mu}=0$ and $\frac{\partial(X^2)}{\partial \sigma}=0$

So if I am not wrong: $$\frac{\partial(X^2)}{\partial \mu} = \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{-2(x_i-\mu)}{\sigma^2}=0$$

and
$$\frac{\partial(X^2)}{\partial \sigma} = -\frac{2}{\sigma^3} \sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)^2=0$$

So for which value of mu and sigma $X^2$ is minimal ? I am a little bit lost in here (sorry I am not very good in statistics), Can you help me ? Because I found $\sigma=\infty$ and $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i)/N$, but by definition $\sigma$ is not $\infty$ so I must be wrong somewhere...

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get $\sigma=0$? Note that you divide by it

Comment: Your derivatives are almosr correct (square missing in the one for variance) but obviously the condition for the variance is that sum of squares of differences of $x_i $ and $\mu $ be zero.

Comment: We can't really achieve zero variance with sample data unless each sample point equals population mean

Comment: One usually uses the Chi squared test on the data

Comment: You are right, it's $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ that is 0, so $\sigma$ goes to infinity... 

So what is the value of $\sigma$ and $\mu$ to minimize  $X2$? I don't understand...

Comment: Can you help me please ?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. The 'basic chi-squared'
distribution is a random variable $Q = \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(k),$
where $Z_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ \\ If you know $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for $X_i  \stackrel{iid}{\sim}{Norm}(\mu,\sigma),$ then $Z_i = (X_i - \mu)/\sigma \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$
However, it is unclear to me why you are treating $Q$ as if it has
parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma.$
// You might look at the non-central chi-squared distribution to see if it
fits a modified version of your question.